# 301 redirect with %0A in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I have this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^12345$ "https://example.com/?prefill_Line1%0ALine2%0A" [R=301]
```

browser redirects my url to:

```
https://example.com/?prefill_Line1ALine2A
```

and I want it to redirect exactly to:

```
https://example.com/?prefill_Line1%0ALine2%0A
```

I want "new line" `%0A` signs to be encoded in the url, but somehow `%0` are being removed.

Comment: To send the "%" symbol in a url, instead try using "%25".

Comment: still "%" doesn't appear in the url

Comment: `RewriteRule ^12345$ "https://example.com/?prefill_Line1%0ALine2%0A" [R=301]` should work . Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: @starkeen it's exactly what I have and it doesn't work, redirects to `https://example.com/?prefill_Line1ALine2A`